# Links are loading without thumbnail images in Facebook

Tags: facebook

Links from our website Pixorange.com is loading without thumbnail images in Facebook. I did use FB lint tool to debug the issue and is giving an error stating that the image is not found.

Here are some links which you can post in FB wall and see that the thumbnail images are not loading with link. The issue is not every links but with some:

http://pixorange.com/tweet-my-weaknesses-to-me-says-modi

http://pixorange.com/rajiv-gandhi-was-entrepreneur-for-swedish-jet

Also when you like the article with FB like button, I am getting an error as follows " is an invalid value for property "object" with type "Reference*"***

We did check our app settings are found that the things are ok and also we did change our server from Hostgator to Inmotion hosting. I opened a ticket with hosting provider and FB developer, still they are not able to find the reason why the link is not loading.

Thanks,

Aswathi Achu

Comment: I have also placed a Bug report to FB, here is details:

Comment: I think now it is okay

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `<meta>` tag in the `<head>` section like:

```
<meta content='100003340872784' property='fb:admins'/>
```

Replace the `100003340872784` with your own facebook user id.  You can get your facebook user id from [here](http://findmyfacebookid.com/).

Regards to Team [Trickonics](http://www.Trickonics.com).